# Am I doing something wrong with my iframe in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, iframe

I saw some posts about iframe and reactjs on stackoverflow but they all want to pass in some args/variables to render. I just want to load a page.

say the page link is "https://some.page.to.load.com"

and I did

```
<iframe src="https://some.page.to.load.com" width="100%"/>
```

But all I get is an empty block that doesn't render any content. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Why do you wanna load iframe in an html? Why not in a component?

Comment: I don't know the difference honestly..... react noob

Comment: I searched on internet and everyone wants to do it in component only. I think using it in component will be the best choice, after all react is mostly about reusable components.